# Как изменить шрифт для textview в spinner?

Tags: android-spinner, android-xml

Это textview, из которого сделан spinner. Как задать пользовательский шрифт? Он у меня в папке assets\fonts\BeauSansPro.ttf

simple_spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvForSpinners"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</RelativeLayout>


protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
        Spinner spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayList<simpleItem> shapesList = new ArrayList<>();
        shapesList.add(new simpleItem("100", R.drawable.fon2));
        shapesList.add(new simpleItem("200", R.drawable.fon2));
        ShapeAdapter mAdapter = new ShapeAdapter(this, shapesList);
        spinner1.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        BeauSansPro = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/BeauSansPro.ttf");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сначала загрузите файл .ttf нужного шрифта (arial.ttf). Поместите его в папку assets (папка "Внутренние ресурсы" создайте новую папку с именем шрифты и поместите ее внутри нее). Если txtyour - это textviews, который вы хотите применить к шрифту, используйте следующий фрагмент кода в onCreate

```
   Typeface Hrift= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Kokila.ttf"); 
   txtyour.setTypeface(Hrift);
```

или вместо *txtyour.setTypeface(Hrift);* можно в xml:

```
   <TextView"
      android:typeface="Hrift"
   </TextView>
```

Comment: как из onCreate взаимодействовать с textview, который не принадлежит activity_main? tvForSpinners находится в  simple_spinner_item.xml, который создан чтобы сделать item для spinner. Всё работает, как надо, но хотелось бы к tvForSpinners применить шрифт.

Comment: Наверно будет не правильно но как вариант
Создать MainActivity2 который будет обращаться к simple_spinner_item.xml и через него делать